# Allow all value on choice field type in Symfony2 form builder

Tags: php, forms, symfony, formbuilder, choicefield

I have a problem for a while and I have read a lot on this topic with similar problem but cant implement the answers in my case.

I have a select field that I populate with Ajax. so in my form builder I have this code :

> VilleType.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MDB\AnnonceBundle\Entity\RegisterRepository")
 */
class VilleType extends AbstractType {

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
                ->add('nomComplet', 'choice'
        );
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'MDB\AdresseBundle\Entity\Ville'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName() {
        return 'mdb_adressebundle_ville';
    }

}
```

But my form never validates because their is no value in this choice field. But I can't add the value inside cause I don't know in advance what user will enter as a value.

So my question is how to disable verification on this field from Symfony. Or allow it to accept all value.

Thanks

> **EDIT**

Here, I tried a new approach. I use The event Listener to modify my field with the value than the user submitted.

```
   public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {

        $builder
                ->add('nomComplet', 'choice');


        $builder->get('nomComplet')->addEventListener(
                FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function(FormEvent $event) /* use ($formModifier) */ {

                    $ville = $event->getData();
                    $event->getForm()->add('nomComplet', 'choice', array('choices' => $ville));
                    // $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $ville);
                }
        );
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'MDB\AdresseBundle\Entity\Ville'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName() {
        return 'mdb_adressebundle_ville';
    }

}
```

> MDB\AdresseBundle\Entity\Ville.php

```
<?php

namespace MDB\AdresseBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Ville
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MDB\AdresseBundle\Entity\VilleRepository");
 */
class Ville
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nomComplet", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nomComplet;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nomClean", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nomClean;


    /**
     * @var array
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="cp", type="simple_array")
     */
    private $cp;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set nomComplet
     *
     * @param string $nomComplet
     * @return Ville
     */
    public function setNomComplet($nomComplet)
    {
        $this->nomComplet = $nomComplet;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nomComplet
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getNomComplet()
    {
        return $this->nomComplet;
    }

    /**
     * Set nomClean
     *
     * @param string $nomClean
     * @return Ville
     */
    public function setNomClean($nomClean)
    {
        $this->nomClean = $nomClean;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get nomClean
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getNomClean()
    {
        return $this->nomClean;
    }


    /**
     * Set cp
     *
     * @param array $cp
     * @return Ville
     */
    public function setCp($cp)
    {
        $this->cp = $cp;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get cp
     *
     * @return array 
     */
    public function getCp()
    {
        return $this->cp;
    }

    public function __toString()
{
    return $this->nomComplet;
}

}
```

But still its not working, I have following error:

> You cannot add children to a simple form. Maybe you should set the option "compound" to true?

So if someone know how to use this way with Event Listener it would be great.

Thanks

Comment: please provide us with more details about nomComplet entity field: field type / ORM settings for that field in your entity / values of that field (entity, text / integer)

Comment: Sorry for reply time , you can look at my edit. Thx :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should work

https://github.com/LPodolski/choiceAjaxLoad/blob/master/src/AppBundle/Form/ItemType.php

Entire project demonstrating this case:
https://github.com/LPodolski/choiceAjaxLoad

Code in case file is removed/altered:

```
/**
 * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
 * @param array $options
 */
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('choiceField', 'choice', array(
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'choiceField'
            )
        ))
    ;

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function(FormEvent $event) {
        $form = $event->getForm();
        $data = $event->getData();
        $form->remove('choiceField');
        $form->add('choiceField', 'choice', array(
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'choiceField',
            ),
            'choices' => array(
                $data['choiceField'] => $data['choiceField'],
            )
        ));
    });

    $builder->add('save', 'submit');
}
```

Comment: I dont have the time to test that now but it look like what i need so i make your answer as accepted and will give a feedback later :)
Thanks

Comment: Works fine but now you can add manually more options, and they will be valid choices, is there any way to prevent this ?

Answer (score 1):

> So my question is how to disable verification on this field from Symfony.

According to the [Documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#suppressing-form-validation) you can suppress form validation by using the POST_SUBMIT event and prevent the ValidationListener from being called.

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
    $event->stopPropagation();
}, 900); // Always set a higher priority than ValidationListener
```